# Ajax.InPlaceEditor.prototype: spaces are encoded to '+' after upgraded prototype to 1.7.1

Tags: encoding, prototypejs, compatibility, in-place-editor

I use InPlaceEditor in my code and it worked fine with prototype version 1.6.0.3, but after I upgraded to 1.7.1. All the spaces in the text field are replaced with "+"'s after being saved. What I can do to "disable" InPlaceEditor's text encoding?

The problem here is that what if I have a string "I have a dog + a cat + a parrot". It would be sent to the server as "I+have+a+dog+++a+cat+++a+parrot"

Comment: check which `method` you are using in the `ajaxOptions` object - if you are using a `GET` then the spaces need to be encoded, `POST` usually does not. When you upgraded the Ajax.Request backend is doing that work for you.

Comment: I really think this is a bug with the newest prototype 1.7.1.

I have created a test page on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2HJqM/ that uses the latest prototype (1.7.1) and latest scriptaculous (1.9).

When you go to my test page, fireup Firebug and active the Net tab. Click RUN, then enter "a + b + c", then click on the latest POST request that pops up in the Net tab. You should see on the POST tab: value: a+++b+++c.

Comment: Ajax.Request is using the native `encodeURIComponent()` which is encoding the spaces as `+`. However you can add a `callback` option with an anonymous function and encode it however you want `{
callback: function(form, value) { return 'myparam=' + encodeURIComponent(value) }
}`

Comment: No, encodeURIComponent() does NOT encode spaces as '+'. See my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mHC6T/